# How to remove owner password of a pdf form and leave it editable?

Tags: forms, pdf, encryption, passwords

I have a pdf form I am working on and would like to edit that but it is a government generated form

https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/files/form/g-28.pdf

I tried different tools but all of them are flattening the form. 
We should be able to remove owner password and leave that editable.

Also, if there is any way to do that through any programmable library/ SDK , please let me know.

Comment: If someone else protects his documents, he clearly states that he doesn't want them to be modified.

Comment: In addition to mkl's comment, if you have a legitimate reason to modify the document, you should be able to get an unprotected version from its issuer. So, it might be worthwhile to contact them.